# SAP UI5 Search Function without filtering

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to implement a functionality  to be able to search a word and find it everywhere in my application (actually just something like ctrl+f functionality of modern browsers)

I digged a lot but everything I found from UI5 API  and Samples were about how to Filter the results.  I don't want to filter the results, just want to find all matching words that exist in that page. How can I implement it ? Is there any samples that I couldn't find , which will help me to do the thing I need to do ?

```
var searchField = new sap.m.SearchField({
    placeholder:'search here',
    search: [oController.searchFn,oController]
});
```

And controller :

```
searchFn: function(){ // TODO };
```

Comment: UI5 should not solve this problem. Looks like you have to get all the text nodes within DOM of the page and search there, this is native DOM API functionality. The question is - what are you going to do with found info? Are you going to highlight it or show a list of findings? The solution depends on the main purpose and requirements.

Comment: I believe as  first step, what we want to have is, just to mark the found words. for example if the user searches for the 'X' word, he should see it magically. 

I also have the same thoughts you have that It actually something to do with DOM but still not sure how to handle this problem to be honest.

Comment: just google "how to highlight matching text on a html page"

Comment: But then , it will search whole page. How is it then possible to   limit that functionality only for  the selected portion of the page , lets say in this case under the tableXYZ.

Comment: your requirement is just a specific case of the "whole page". Usually you can decide which DOM element should be the starting point.